# Should I cast all variables to long long to avoid overflow or the leftmost variable is enough?

Tags: c++, overflow

Consider this code

```
int a = 1e6, b = 1e6;
int c = a, d = a;

long long x = (long long) a * b * c * d; 

long long y = (long long) a * b * (long long) c * d;
```

does the right hand expression get evaluated from left to right to guarantee no overflow?

Comment: Are you sure you are using C++? Usually we don't use C-style type casts in C++.

Comment: You get the signed integer overflow in the both cases, thus the question is unclear.

Comment: Weird note: It is unusual, but there's nothing that prevents a C++ implementation making `int` the same size as `long long`. `int` just can't be larger than `long` which in turn can't be larger than `long long`. Back in the day, the big Crays effectively did this. Everything from `char` on up was 32 bit.

Comment: Even `long long` has a finite range of values - just a range that is larger than that of `int`.       Problems in your code arise from (0)  You are initialising an `int` using a floating point value [a bad habit encouraged on some poor quality competition sites]   (1)  an `int` is not even guaranteed to be able to represent `1000000` - in fact, it is not guaranteed to be able to represent more than `32767`. (2) The product of `a`, `b,`, `c`, and `d`, even if using an implementation with an `int` that *can* represent `1000000`, exceeds what a `long long` is guaranteed to be able to represent.

Comment: Ironically, `1e6*1e6*1e6*1e6` does *not* overflow, because it's floating-point. And since it's `double`, it is even representable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ensuring that all operands are `long long`, it's enough to simply cast the leftmost operand to `long long`.

```cpp
long long x = (long long) a * b * c * d;
```

Multiplication is left-associative, meaning that `a * b` happens first at a syntactical level.
The type of the sub-expression `a * b` is `long long`, and so `(a * b) * c` is also multiplication between `long long`s, etc.
This guarantees you that the entire chain of multiplications is happening with more precision than `int`.

**However, the final result of your calculation is 10<sup>24</sup> which requires at least an 81-bit signed integer to represent. `long long` is most likely not wide enough.**

##### Note on overflow safety

Note that generally, it's possible that `a * b * c * d` overflows, even if all operands received double the width by being turned from `int` to `long long`. If this was addition, then it would be safe, assuming that `long long` has double the width of `int`.

##### Note on code quality

In general, it's probably better to use the same degree of precision everywhere, so that you (and future readers of your code) don't have to ask this question.

Comment: @Peter thanks for pointing it out, I've corrected the answer.